# Adding filter to guice servlet

Tags: java, servlets, guice

I created a servlet using guice servet which works fine:

```
protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule() {
        protected void configureServlets() {
            bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class);
            serve("/myservlet").with(MyServlet.class);
        }
    });
}
```

My servlet looks like this:

```
@Inject
private MyService myService;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().print(myService.hello("John Doe").toString());
}
```

Now I am trying to add a filter to it like thing:

```
            bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class);
            filter("/*").through(MyFilter.class);
            serve("/myservlet").with(MyServlet.class);
```

My filter looks like this:

```
@Singleton public class MyFilter implements Filter { 
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { } 
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Yeah"); 
    } 
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

As soon as I add the filter the servlet does not get called any more.

When I remove the filter the servlet works again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does your filter code look like?

Comment: @Singleton
    public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    
    }
    
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Yeah");
    }
    
    public void destroy() {
    
    }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not within you Guice assembly, but with your filter implementation. You will have to call:

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

in your `doFilter` method to pass on the processing through the filter. You can read more about a typical filter in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.FilterChain)).